# inline style stroke-width for axis makes bold tick labels

Tags: d3.js

I do not use css since I want to save and process the created SVG visualisation files. This means I need to use inline styles. So far I experienced d3 as flawless so most likely I did do something wrong.

I am expecting {'stroke-width': '3px'} to make thick axis lines. But it makes bold axis labels. I expected the text to be controlled with font related styles like {'font-style': 'normal'}.

Whats wrong with how I use 'stroke-width'? I tested this in both Chrome and Firefox.

here is my code:

```
<script>
    var margin = {top: 20, right: 10, bottom: 20, left: 40};
    var width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right;
    var height = 100 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    var x = d3.scale.linear().range([0, width]);
    var y = d3.scale.linear().range([0, height]);
    var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x).orient("bottom");
          // .tickFormat(d3.time.format("%H:%M"));
    var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y).orient("left").ticks(height/10);

    var svg = d3.select("svg");
    var vis = svg.append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")")
        .style({'font-size': '10px', 'font-family': 'sans-serif',
            'font-style': 'normal', 'font-variant': 'normal', 
            'font-weight': 'normal'});

    var redraw = function(selection, data, style) {
        selection.selectAll(".bar")
            .data(data)
          .enter().append("rect")
            .attr('class', "bar")
            .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d[0]) - .5; })
            .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d[1]); })
            .attr("width", 5)
            .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d[1]);  })
            .style(style);

        vis.select(".x.axis").call(xAxis);
        vis.select(".y.axis").call(yAxis);
    };

    svg.attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom);

    vis.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .style({ 'stroke': 'Black', 'fill': 'none', 'stroke-width': '3px'})
      .call(xAxis);

    vis.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .style({ 'stroke': 'Black', 'fill': 'none', 'stroke-width': '3px'})
      .call(yAxis);

    // now we draw the first barchart (we do not know about the 2nd one yet)
    var data1 = [[2,0.5], [4,0.8], [6,0.6], [8,0.7], [12,0.8]];
    x.domain([0, 13]);
    y.domain([0.9, 0]);

    vis.append("g")
      .attr("class", "bar1");

    vis.select(".bar1")
      .call(redraw, data1, {'fill': 'Red', 'stroke': 'Black'});
</script>
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I built on the answer of explunit and applied the stroke-width more selectively. Here is what I ended up with:

```
 vis.selectAll('.axis line, .axis path')
     .style({'stroke': 'Black', 'fill': 'none', 'stroke-width': '3px'});
```

Answer (score 10):

The `.call` to the axis functions give you a nice way to create all those line and text elements in one go, but there's nothing to stop you from then coming back to select individual pieces of what was created and give it further styling. Something like this:

```
var yAxisNodes = vis.append("g")
  .attr("class", "y axis")
  .style({ 'stroke': 'Black', 'fill': 'none', 'stroke-width': '3px'})
  .call(yAxis);
yAxisNodes.selectAll('text').style({ 'stroke-width': '1px'});
```